# How to pass a string value to v-model that points to a data object (dynamic evaluation)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to pass an object value (`product.id`) to a `v-model` of an input. The problem is when I do that, I get a string "product.id" not `product.id` as an object. How can I convert the string? Or is this the wrong way?

I tried JSON.parse, but it was not working.

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="field in fields" :key="field.id">
      <label>{{ field.name }}</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="field.model" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
      data() {
        return {
          product: {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            price: ''
          },
          fields: [
            {
              name: 'Name 1',
              model: 'product.id',
            }, 
            {
              name: 'Name 2',
              model: 'product.name',
            }, 
            {
              name: 'Name 3',
              model: 'product.price',
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you wanted to do this, but since `v-model` only takes an object, one way I can think of is to [reassign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) the `field.model`s with the **evaluated versions** as object. Not necessarily a good approach but works:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      product: {
        id: '112233',
        name: 'Random name',
        price: '$34.5'
      },

      fields: [{
          name: 'Name 1',
          model: 'product.id',
        },
        {
          name: 'Name 2',
          model: 'product.name',
        },
        {
          name: 'Name 3',
          model: 'product.price',
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    specialFields() {
      return this.fields.map(item => Object.assign(item, {
        model: eval(`this.${item.model}`)
      }));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="field in specialFields" :key="field.id">
    <label>{{ field.name }}</label>
    <input type="text" v-model.trim="field.model" />
  </div>
</div>
```